# Downloading file from server ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, download, mime-types, tesseract

I need to download tesseract/ocr file from server to mobile device, that have extention *.traineddata
How to do this? 
I tried this, but it returns me file without extention with name `Download`

```
public FileResult Download(string fileName)
{
    var dir = Server.MapPath("~/Repository/MobileAPI/");
    return File(dir + fileName, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change you `return` statement like following

```
 return File(dir + fileName, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileName);
```

Here third parameter is download file name.